# How would I create a dynamic login button in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-inside">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="top-menu">
            <a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">About</a> | <a href="#">Contact</a> | 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add a login button there that will detect whether or not the user is logged in, and if the user is it will turn into "logout".  I am using Membership Services so I would use MembershipUser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your `Request` object you can use `Request.IsAuthenticated`(MSDN docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated.aspx)) which will work regardless of how you manage your users behind the scenes, as long as it plugs into the system ASP .NET provides.

Example:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated){
  <div id="logout_button"/>
} else {
  <div id="login_button"/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Request.IsAuthenticated` to detect whether a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated %>
```

or

```
<% Request.IsAuthenticated %> should do the trick
```

Comment: Your code is using the older ASP .NET WebForms tags. In ASP .NET MVC 3 the default engine is the Razor ViewEngine which uses the Razor Expression Language. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx His example uses it too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet based on _LogOnPartial.cshtml from default project template:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {        
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account"))
    {
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log Off" />
    }
}
else
{
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```